# Destructor errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, class, destructor

I have this class:

```
class A{

  private:

    int * intArr;

    int countInt;

  public:

    A(){
      countInt=0;
    }

    SetArray(countInt){
      intArr=new int[countInt];
    }

    ~A(){
      delete []intArr;
    }

};
```

And I also have this class:

```
#define MAX_SIZE 10
class B{

  private:

    A * Aelements;

  public:

    B(){
      int num;
      Aelements=new A[MAX_SIZE];
      //reading number from file
      //....
      //num=something
      for(int i=0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++)
        Aelements[i].SetArray(num);
    }

    static void  test(){
      try{
        B b;
        //do something...
      } //here supposed to call ~A()
      catch(){
        //handle errors....
      }
    };
```

Class `B` creates array of `A` elements by using the `A` default constructor and then calling  `SetArray()` to create the `int` array to each `A` element.

My problems are:

1. When I call `B::test()`, it doesn't call `~A()`. The calling to the `A`'s destructor should happened when `try{}` is finished.
2. And if I force calling it, by making `~B()`:

   ```
   ~B()
   {
     delete [] Aelements; //Calling ~A()
   }
   ```

   I get this message after calling `~A()` (when `try{}` is finished):

   > Debug Assertion Failed!
   >      _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

How can I use the destructors in the correct way?

Comment: 1. Why would `A~()` be called? You haven't deleted the dynamically allocated array of `A`. 2. Show some code that produces that failure. Most likely, you need to follow *the rule of three*.

Comment: That's a lot of `new` and `delete` for C++. Have you considered using standard containers?

Comment: What do you mean by standard containers?

Comment: @user3572267 A standard container is something like `std::vector` or `std::list`. What you're making appears similar to `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

An object created with a `new` expression exists until it's destroyed by a `delete` expression (or equivalent code).

You don't have any `delete` expressions, or objects that do that for you, so the `new`-ed objects just go on existing.

A direct fix would be to use a smart pointer such as `std::unique_ptr` instead of a raw pointer. A better fix would be to use a `std::vector` instead of DIY raw arrays. These fixes take charge of copying in different ways: `std::unique_ptr` disables copying (it can be moved but not copied), while `std::vector` supports copying.